# Google mobile ads Update issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-mobile-ads

I have update project version 2019.4. to 2021.3. Then update Google mobile ads plugin update 8.4.0 then this error cs0246: the type or namespace name 'rewardbasedvideoad' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Appear on console

Comment: Use this new [API](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded) of admob.

Comment: Example link please

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded

Comment: Any tutorial for beginners

Comment: I'm new to unity So do you want help with me to Update my Admanager code

Answer (score 0):

If [migrating from the older version](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/migration) is difficult or unproductive for you, you can instead try removing the way you are currently managing it and re-adding it from scratch as described in [the rewarded ads tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded) as mentioned [by @jaimin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786003/google-mobile-ads-update-issue#comment135371454_76786003).

The combination of the two docs should explain what is new and how/why to do each part.